# convergence of a series with logarithm

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I've been dealing with the convergence of the following series for a while:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ln\sqrt[n]{1+\frac{x}{n}}$$.
I've tried the Cauchy test and found it reduces to study the convergence of
$$\ln\left({1+\frac{x}{2^n}}\right)$$
But now I don't know how to study this one, hope someone may help. Thanks
P.S According to the book it should converge for $x>-1$

Comment: sorry, i had forgotten the main part

Comment: Hint: for $a>0$ it is $\log(a^b)=b \log a$ and it is $\log(1+t) \le t$ for all $t>-1$.

Comment: I've written what I've done so far

Answer (score 2):

Note that [Cauchy Condensation Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)(Which you have applied) is valid for a **non-increasing** sequence of **non-negative terms**. So you should be careful as when $x<0$ the sequence is increasing .

Rather just use this :-

You can show by elementary calculus that $\ln(1+x)\leq x$. Also it is evident from the graph.

So $\frac{1}{n}\ln(1+\frac{x}{n})\leq \frac{x}{n^{2}}$.

As $\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ converges you have convergence for all $x>-1$.

And the reason for $x>-1$ is just that the series becomes undefined for $x\leq -1$ as $\log(1-x)$ becomes undefined(The term for $n=1$).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had forgotten the hypotheses of Cauchy: I must be more careful when I apply these theorems. I had also thought that the matter with x>-1 was that the logarithm was somehow undefined but I missed the point: again, thanks

Comment: @AlessandroTassoni You can mark as answer then

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron +1. A question: you've said that it must be $x>-1$ because of the domain of the logarithm, but I notice that it is $1+x/n>0 \iff x>-n$. Now, I assume that you said that it must be $x>-1$ because $x>-n$ must hold for any $n \ge 1$ (since the summation is for $n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$, but it is just my guess. I mean, is the inequality $x>-n \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$ equivalent to $x>-1$?

Comment: For all $x<-1$ . one of the terms of the series is undefined. You obviously only need to check in the domain for convergence....outside the domain nothing makes sense. The domain of $\ln(1+x)$ is $(-1,\infty)$ . So you only need to check over there. Outside this the term for $n=1$ does not make sense.